# Multiple conditional probability | Conditional Probability for X given by multiple variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am reading Duda's Pattern classification (2nd ed)

In page 38 ( Chapter 3: Maximum likelihood and bayesian estimation), I do not know how they obtain the following.

$$P(X\mid e^p) = P(x\mid e_{\mathcal{P}1},e_{\mathcal{P}2},\ldots,e_{\mathcal{P}|\mathcal{P}|}) \tag A$$

$$ \sum_{\text{all } i,j,\ldots, k} P(x\mid\mathcal{P}_{1i},\mathcal{P}_{2j},\ldots,P_{|\mathcal{P}|k})\ P(\mathcal{P}_{1i},\mathcal{P}_{2j},\ldots,\mathcal{P}_{|\mathcal{P}|k}\mid e_{\mathcal{P}1},\ldots,e_{\mathcal{P}|\mathcal{P}|}) \tag B$$

$$ \sum_{\text{all } i,j,\ldots\,,\, k} P(x\mid\mathcal{P}_{1i},\mathcal{P}_{2j},\ldots,P_{|\mathcal{P}|k})\ P(\mathcal{P}_{1i}\mid e_{\mathcal{P}1})\
P(\mathcal{P}_{|\mathcal{P}|k}\mid e_{\mathcal{P}|\mathcal{P}|k}) \tag C$$

I am unable to comprehend on how or what rule the author used to derived from Eq A to Eq B and subsequently Eq C.

I really appreciate if some one can provide good reference or hint to this problem

Comment: What is $\mathcal{P}$? Could you clarify your notation?

Comment: Hi @Sisyphus, thanks for replying

This thread is relating to Bayesian Networks. Specifically, the above equation was to determine the probaility at hidden note,**x**  given the evidence,**e** from multiple parents node, **P**

For clarity on the aforementioned network, please see the figure from this link [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ffd8q4yzZQrY_SJPKgba4KFPXMWKRFIO).